# Struggling to find a shiny workaround to flush data from $finished while using EditMod in the mapEdit package

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, mapview

This is a crosspost from the mapedit issues github page [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit/issues/106). I am attempting to build a shiny app that allows a user to plot a subset of data after selecting polygons using the `mapedit` package. While I am able to successfully plot the data using `mapedit`, I am unable to flush the `$finished` data after the selected mapedit polygons are deleted.

This produces two errors that I have yet to determine a workaround for, 1) if the plot collapses as seen in the gif below an error `the argument is of length zero`, and 2) if the plot does not collapse, the last selected `$finished` data remains with no ability to clear the data from the plot.

Is there anything that can be done to solve these issues?

Below is a reproducible example from r-spatial [blog](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/06/09/mapedit_0-2-0.html) *mapedit - updates in 0.2.0*. In my shiny app I am using the `mapedit` package to subset a different time series using object ids and plot a timeseries in `plotly`. I believe the underlying issue can be solved using the reproducible example below.

```
library(sf)    
# make the coordinates a numeric matrix
qk_mx <- data.matrix(quakes[,2:1])
# convert the coordinates to a multipoint feature
qk_mp <- st_multipoint(qk_mx)
# convert the multipoint feature to sf
qk_sf <- st_sf(st_cast(st_sfc(qk_mp), "POINT"), quakes, crs=4326)

# run select demo for the quake data
#  we will need the qk_sf
#  to test
# plot(qk_sf)

library(mapedit)
library(mapview)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    # edit module ui
    column(6, editModUI("editor")),
    column(
      6,
      h3("Boxplot of Depth"),
      plotOutput("selectstat")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # edit module returns sf
  edits <- callModule(editMod, "editor", mapview(qk_sf)@map)

  output$selectstat <- renderPlot({
    req(edits()$finished)
    qk_intersect <- st_intersection(edits()$finished, qk_sf)
    req(nrow(qk_intersect) > 0) 
    boxplot(
      list(
        all = as.numeric(qk_sf$depth),
        selected = as.numeric(qk_intersect$depth)
      ),
      xlab = "depth"
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Although I have posted this, along with others in the mapedit github issues page and r-spatial, I figured it would be worthwhile to see if there is a solution that doesn't require a package fix.

Answer (score 1):

this is resolved on GitHub at https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit/issues/106.
`remotes::install_github("r-spatial/mapedit")` solves the issue in the mapedit source code pending a package fix.